# Merging mkv file chapters into one chapter

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv

How would you merge chapters in mkv files into one chapter? I've only found threads about adding, removing and splitting chapters. I'm looking for a command line tool. Can ffmpeg be used for this?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases **ffmeg** only can help.

Create a file **mylist.txt** with all the files you want to have concatenated in the following form (lines starting with a # are ignored):

```
# this is a comment
file '/path/to/file1.mkv'
file '/path/to/file2.mkv'
file '/path/to/file3.mkv'
```

Note that these can be either relative or absolute paths. Then you can stream copy or re-encode your files:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mkv
```

The `-safe 0` above is not required if the paths are relative.
The `-c copy` try concat files without re-encoding. Try remove this params if something will wrong. I mean **mkv** is a just container can included inside any codecs like h.264 (MPEG-4 AVC), MPEG-2, VC-1, MPEG-2, mpeg-4 / Xvid / DivX.. It need to know which one encoder\decoder codec(s) installed or not with your ffmpeg. Need know exactly or just try. But this is another question. Let's assume that **your ffmpeg** install **fully support your current mkv's codecs**.

Source: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: Perhaps I wasen't clear enough. I'm looking for a way to merge chapters inside let's say name_of_movie.mkv into one chapter. I dont want to merge several movies together. I found an option in handbrake, which does exactly what I want but I'm still looking for a command line alternative, which could be used in a script. I find it a bit odd if you cannot do this on the command line. I'm using linux btw. PS4 is not able to play movies, which are split into chapters. Sorry for the missleading question and the use of loose definiton. Working with media files is a new territory for me.

Comment: Can you explain without "chapter" term, just using files terms? And what you mean when told "merge chapters inside"? PS4 can play only specific codecs (for example h.264). File extension like **mkv** don't have a relation to codecs.

Comment: It's possible to placess markers (starting points) at different points in the video so you can easily jump to them using the keyboard. Let's say I have a 1 h long video presentation and at 25.18 I bring up something interesting. I can place a marker at 25.18 and when I press some key on the keyboard I will get to 25.18. They are called chapter markers but people seem to refer to them as chapters. Now I have mkv movies, which have up to 4 chapter markers. I did a comparison between the mkv movies that worked on Ps4 ad the one's that didn't using handbrake and I noticed that the one's

Comment: that didn't work had 4 chapters markers. The one's that worked had only one chapter marker. I would like one chapter marker instead of 4.

Comment: You mean metadata markers: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Metadata-1

Comment: Yes! You are right. Now I need to figure out how to get only one chapter marker. I think I need to extract the metadata and find out the length of the whole video, edit the metadata and load it back to the mkv container. I'm not sure if it's that straightforward. You seem to know your way around ffmpeg. Do you know how to get only one chapter marker with ffmpeg?